# Is Jersey client querying REST support retry mechanism like Resteasy

Tags: java, linux, rest, dns, jersey

I am trying to query a rest service hosted with **DNS** name.The DNS name points to 2 LoadBalancer  IP's that points to the actual REST service.

If both the LoadBalancer's are up the query is working fine with jersey client,whereas if one of the LoadBalancer is down and the `nslookup` gives the first server as the ip which is down then the jersey client fails with Connection refused and don't even fallback to the other DNS IP which is alive.

The same when tried with `wget` or `curl` it works by falling back to the alive REST server.

Please let me know what should be configured on jersey client config or `WebResource` or if any other to make the client to retry with the other ips attached to the our **DNS** host-name.

I am using  below code

```
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig.DefaultClientConfig()
    client = Client.create(clientConfig);
 WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
```

I am using `jersey-client-1.9.1.jar`

Please let me know if i have to add more information.